# pl/sql procedure containing for loop and if loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

**I have written pl/sql code to check whether elements in one column is greater than the average value of that same column**

```
set serveroutput on;
        DECLARE
         v_count   Number := 0;
         v_num Number := 0;
         v_xVal  tblNewData.xValue%type;
     v_avgX Number := 0;
        BEGIN
        SELECT round(avg(xValue),2)
          INTO v_avgX
          FROM tblNewData;
           For i IN 1 .. v_count LOOP
            SELECT xValue
            INTO v_xVal 
            FROM tblNewData
        where dataID = i * 10;

                v_num := v_num + 1;

        if (v_xVal > v_avgX) then
          dbms_output.put_line('x value greater than y average ' || v_xVal);

        end if;
       end LOOP;



      END;
```

however, the above code says procedures successfully completed but did not provide the desired output. 
Please tell me what is wrong with above output

Comment: Do you need to write a procedure or SQL query will work as well?

Comment: @ketub.. i have to write procedure

Comment: What is the "desired output"?  What is the actual output?  Where is your reproducible test case?

Comment: In `For i IN 1 .. v_count LOOP` v_count is 0, so loop is never iterated..

Comment: @dhruvkadia have you modified something in your code? if yes then post updated code.

Comment: @dhruvkadia `v_num := v_num + 1;`  why this?

Comment: @JustinCave desired output is that loop should go through all the values in column and comapre it with average value of that same column and give result for values which are greater than average value

Comment: @dhruvkadia initialize v_count to the number of rows you want to iterate through then.

Comment: @ketub identified the issue.  If you posted a better question, though, you would make it much easier to get better answers.  "did not provide the desired output" could mean that the code outputted something but you believe that the output was incorrect (i.e. it said 2 was greater than the average when the average should be 5).  It could mean that you got a compilation error.  It could mean that you got a runtime error.  It could mean that you got no output.  If you aren't clear about the problem, you're forcing people to guess at what the problem might be and we might guess wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Also the `select into` inside the loop might not return any rows.

The general logic of reporting rows where a value is greater than the average can be done in a query along the lines of:

```
select sequence_name
     , 'Value ' || cache_size || ' is greater than median ' || med_cache_size as warning
from   ( select sequence_name
              , cache_size
              , median(cache_size) over() as med_cache_size
         from   user_sequences )
where  cache_size > med_cache_size;
```

(I've used `user_sequences` and `median` to create a simple test case, but you can substitute `tblnewdata` and `avg`.)

Comment: for some reason dhruv wants a procedure.

Comment: Yes, I almost almost added a note to say he can wrap that in his own `create or replace procedure x as begin ... end;` if he really wants to, but it seemed obvious ;)

Comment: apologies for not seeing the obvious :)